# Unable to reproduce exact results for the "100-sided die puzzle" via simulation in R

Tags: r, probability, numerical-methods, montecarlo

I am trying to replicate the results mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372638/100-sided-die-probability) using R. While I am able to get quite close to the theoretical number, it's still not quite there and I am not sure where I am going wrong.

The strategy that I am using is, roll till an "a" or a larger value is encountered, in which case, stop playing and collect your winnings.

This is simulated 1000 times, for each value of "a" (which itself varies from 1 to 100), by using the replicate function. I maintain records of what value of "a" gave rise to what expected value.

Finally, I choose the entry for the maximum expected value.

To provide an example:

1) 100-sided dice

2) `a = data.frame(a = 1:100)`

3) For each value of a, I run a simulation to check what the estimated value will be. **One example: a = 30; die rolls = 23, 22, 2, 12, 38...** In this case, the player continues to roll till they roll 38, at which point they stop (as 38 is larger than "a" here) and collect $38 as their winnings. Actual gain = $38 - $4 = $34

4) Step 3 is repeated 1000 times (each value of "a" gets 1000 runs). The final expected value chosen is the **mean of all these 1000 runs**

5) I end up with a data frame like: `a = data.frame(a = 1:100, ev = c(50.5, 51.6, 52... 12.2, 10.93))` from which I can see that the maximal expected value is **87.xyz** where xyz is the decimal part.

The problem that I am facing is that **I cannot seem to be able to replicate the 87.3571 figure in the original link** (which is backed up by the theoretical calculation)...

I have noted that increasing the number of trials from 1000 to 10,000 towards 100,000 takes the expected value closer to the figure in the link. Is this the only way to increase accuracy or am I overlooking something? This seems like a situation where I am messing up by overlooking some subtle difference only a statistician understands...

Some other information:

1) I set.seed to a fixed number at the beginning of the function. This means that set.seed is called only once for the entire function (irrespective of number of trials).

Comment: This is just standard behavior involving law of large numbers, isn't it? The theoretical average of rolling a single 6-sided die is 3.5, but if you simulate it with a finite number of rolls you'll just get a number close to that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @jeffcarey. I just wanted to make sure that there wasn't any oversight on my part. Based on my description, do you see any red flags other than residual error due to finite rolls?